# How to choose database structure?

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design

I have a two entities Storage, Items. Items are stored in the storages. Items have a different types. For example, Item types are Resources, Weapon. Weapons have unique item instance characteristics "damaged".

Resources doesn't have any unique instance characteristics, and can be stacked to another existing instance by increasing count.

I have multiples way to do it:

1. Save all in one table: `storage_items` (id, item_id, count, damaged) and create partial index on `item_id` with condition COUNT IS NOT NULL
2. Separate it into two tables by types (`storage_resources`, `storage_weapons`)
3. Create two tables `storage_items` (storage_items_id, item_id,count) and `items_properties` (id, storage_items_id, damaged).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to have different subtypes linked to a common table is to use type codes to distinguish the link. For example:

```
create table Storage(
    ID       serial,
    ItemType char( 1 ) not null,
    ..., -- Fields common to all items
    constraint CK_StorageType check ItemType in( 'R', 'W' ),
    primary key( ID, ItemType )
);
```

The ID field will itself be unique, so you may need or just want to have it the PK all by itself. You can have this instead:

```
create table Storage(
    ID       serial,
    ItemType char( 1 ),
    ..., -- Fields common to all items
    constraint CK_StorageType check ItemType in( 'R', 'W' ),
    primary key( ID ),
    constraint UQ_IdItem unique( ID, ItemType )
);
```

Either way, create a separate table for each type of item:

```
create table ResourceItems(
    ID       int not null,
    ItemType char( 1 ) not null,
    ..., -- Fields unique to Resource items
    constraint ResourceItemType check( ItemType = 'R' ),
    primary key( ID, ItemType ),
    constraint FK_ResourceItem_Storage( ID, ItemType )
        references Storage( ID, ItemType )
);

create table WeaponItems(
    ID       int not null,
    ItemType char( 1 ) not null,
    ..., -- Fields unique to Weapon items
    constraint WeaponItemType check( ItemType = 'W' ),
    primary key( ID, ItemType ),
    constraint FK_WeaponItem_Storage( ID, ItemType )
        references Storage( ID, ItemType )
);
```

So you must designate all Storage entries as either an R or W type. All Resource entries must have an entry in Storage defined as R and all Weapon entries must have a Storage entry defined as W. This allows you to have different types of items while keeping them firmly segregated, maintaining data integrity.